# Использование команды grep в цикле while в bash

Tags: bash, while, grep

`while [ pbm status | grep "Currently running" ]` - в цикле хочу выполнить вот такую команду, но возникает ошибка `` -bash: line 5: [: missing `]' grep: ]: No such file or directory ``. Проблема в том что команда grep считывает квадратную скобку, которая нужна для задания условия цикла, и выдает ошибку. Подскажите как можно исправить эту ошибку, пожалуйста

Comment: `while [[ -n $(pbm status | grep "Currently running") ]]` - возможно так получится

Comment: @PotroNik спасибо, твой ответ помог и цикл заработал

Comment: @PotroNik, можно же без башизмов и проверок строк. Учимся опередлять код ошибки и подавлять вывод `grep`.

Comment: @0andriy тег баш присутствует, поэтому и с башизмом, но на ответ не претендую)

Answer (score 1):

Для проверки статуса команды скобки не нужны:

```
while echo "if" | grep "if"; do sleep 1; echo '.'; done
```

Comment: А куда вывод `grep` пойдёт?

Comment: В консоль. Но можно и приглушить `grep -q "if"`.